# Apache Camel: InOut with different Endpoint

Tags: spring, request, apache-camel, ibm-mq, reply

currently I am working with apache camel to write and read from Websphere MQ.

On my project, I have 2 WMQ: 1 for write (Queue.W) and 1 for read (Queue.R). Here is how I configure my apps:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" default-init-method="init" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xs http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi  http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/components.xml"/>

    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <dataFormats>
            <xmljson id="xmljson" forceTopLevelObject="true" skipNamespaces="true" removeNamespacePrefixes="true"/>
        </dataFormats>

        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8888/uebermittleAusweisdaten"/>
            <process ref="TransformToXML"/>
            <to uri ="xslt:mobako.sender.xsl"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelJmsDestinationName">
                <constant>queue:///Queue.W?targetClient=1</constant>    
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="JMS_IBM_Character_Set">
                <constant>ISO8859_1</constant>    
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="jms:queue:Queue.W" pattern="InOnly"/>
            <to uri="direct:result" pattern="InOut"/>
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="jms:queue:Queue.R"/>
            <marshal ref="xmljson"/>
            <to uri="direct:result"/>
        </route>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

What I want to do is: send back the response from read queue (Queue.R) to http endpoint on my first flow.

To achieve that, I tried to use InOut pattern. However, it seems the InOut pattern only worked when I have same endpoint (For example if the outbound on my first flow is Queue.W, then the inbound on my second flow should be Queue.W too). But, since I used different WMQ for write and read, I can not make it work.

As can be seen in my configuration, I tried to solve it by adding inOnly pattern to my Queue.W and then adding

```
<to uri="direct:result" pattern="InOut"/>
```

After that on my second flow, I tried to send back the response from Queue.R by adding

```
<to uri="direct:result"/>
```

But it also did not work! Moreover, after I do so, I got following error:

> org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException:
>   No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://result].
>   Exchange[Message: http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap/uebermittleAusweisdatenurn:uuid:ID-FRA000000085404-64407-1402571267690-0-2esbp://services.fraport.de/lsmh/mobakoesbp://services.fraport.de/lsmh/zks-eapesbp://services.fraport.de/lsmh/mobako12.1]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:149)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelFilterWrapper.doFilter(CamelFilterWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any sugestion about how to solve my problem? Thanks so much. Your help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the `InOut` pattern is designed to be used with `direct:` routes.

As you noted, `InOut` is designed to be used with (for example, with JMS messages) where you send and expext a response from the same endpoint (for example, JMS Queue).

In the case of `InOut` with JMS messages, there is a lot of functionality regarding correlation ID's under the hood to make that work - that's why I can't see how this would work cleanly with a `direct:xyz` endpoint.

Instead, why don't you separate your two routes, and if you need to synchronize them (so that you verify you got a response) use a third route with a completion timeout.

```
    <route>
        <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8888/uebermittleAusweisdaten"/>
        <!-- ... -->
        <to uri="jms:queue:Queue.W" pattern="InOnly"/>
        <!-- set Body or Property with some unique ID to indicate request -->
        <to uri="direct:responseChecker"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:Queue.R"/>
        <marshal ref="xmljson"/>
        <!-- set Body or Property with some unique ID to indicate response -->
        <to uri="direct:responseChecker"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:responseChecker"/>
        <!-- check request vs response, use a bean / aggregator with a completion timeout -->
    </route>
```

I hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: hi @vikingsteve, i am new to apache camel, so could you please explain a bit or give an example  about how can I "<!-- check request vs response, use a bean / aggregator with a completion timeout -->"? And about the unique id, do you mean I need to set a correlation id? Thanks